# Do the given lines form a triangle?

Tags: triangle-inequality

> Let ABC be an equilateral triangle and let M be a point that does not
> lie on the circle circumscribed on the triangle. Show that the
> segments AM, BM and CM can form sides of a triangle. Hint: Check that
> the triangle inequalities $AM<BM+CM$, $BM<AM+CM$ and $CM<AM+BM$ hold.

[image]

**My attempt:**

The circle circumscribed on the triangle is
shown in the figure.
At the intersection of BM and AC, we put a point P. Now we find that in $\triangle{AMC}$:
$$AP+PM \geq AM$$ and $$PC+PM\geq CM$$
Then we form the equivalent triangle inequalities for  $\triangle{ABC}$, which are $$AP+PB\geq AB$$ and $$BP+PC\geq BC.$$ . Furthermore, we can form the additional triangle inequalities $$MC+CB\geq BM$$ and $$BA+AM\geq BM$$. Clearly, we see that every  side in each given triangle inequalities are part of triangles, and hence $AM, \ BM, \ CM$ all form sides of a triangle.

But if one wants to prove that $AM, BM, CM$ alone form a triangle, it is not so trivial from the given reasoning. Is there any way to do this here?

Any hints appreciated